# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, android-studio

In android studio, I will get this error.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute apt
please any one help me. How to resolve it.

view console

[image]

Comment: try deleting build folder & then building it again....

Comment: post your attributes

Comment: If you don't mind please tell me which build folder app->build or main project->build @TUSHAR

Comment: app->build folder

Comment: i will try but still get this error @TUSHAR

Comment: I guess the problem is with your values.xml can you post your values.xml here.

Comment: @androiddeveloper see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution it is a my mistake, I forgot to remove one style from style.xml, So it will give this error .

Answer (score 1):

I also had same issue. I updated my windows from 7 to 10, then I start Android Studio and i got same error. I solved it by changing in build.gradle to

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1')
```

If you are using react native then you can upgrade it to

```
project(':react-native-fbsdk') {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in my android studio and I got the same error which you are getting. I found the solution.

Change the name of **"values.xml"** file with some other name. You are getting the error because you put the **values.xml** file inside the **values folder** so it conflicting your file. You need to rename the values.xml and it works like a charm.

Comment: No in my values directory there is no values.xml file :( now what to do but when I run my app that time it will fetch from res->merged->debug->values->values.xml what to do? @Andy Developer

Answer (score 0):

In my case when i was upgrade **gradle** to **4.1** then it was happened.my sugesstion is that don't upgrade **gradle** to **4.1** in **android studio 3.0** because it is possible to **mismatch sdk tools**.