# Android card guessing game throws MainActivity not declared among other errors

Tags: android

I tried to build and run from the following [sample](http://www.programering.com/a/MzM4QTMwATI.html) but I'm getting couple errors:

> 1- Error running MainActivity: The activity 'MainActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml
>   2- Error:(553, 69) String types not allowed (at 'activity_horizontal_margin' with value '').
>   3- Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.>
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Can somebody tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Every activity should be declared in AndroidManifest file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122386/activity-declaration-in-androidmanifest-xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity Declaration in AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122386/activity-declaration-in-androidmanifest-xml)

Comment: I read that page before asking my question and read couple other pages and tested their suggestion. But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The first error ("The activity 'MainActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml") means exactly what it says. There is a file in your project named `AndroidManifest.xml` and you must declare all `Activity`s in this file. Here's the manifest created by Android Studio for a new project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.test.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Two important things to note:

1) The `package` attribute of the `<manifest>` tag (on line 3 in this example) must match the package name you're using for your Java code.

2) There must be an `<activity>` tag for your `MainActivity` (see line 12 in the example).

The second error ("String types not allowed (at 'activity_horizontal_margin')") is harder to debug without your code, but here's a guess. The page you linked two includes these two lines:

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

You have to make sure (a) that you did not remove the `@dimen/` prefix from these, and (b) that you have declared a `dimen` resource with the name `activity_horizontal_margin`. Usually that would be done by creating `res/values/dimens.xml` with content something like:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

You could also replace these `dimen` resource references with in-place values, like this:

```
android:paddingLeft="16dp" 
android:paddingRight="16dp"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for detail information. I'm testing it right now and hopefully it will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- Error running MainActivity: The activity 'MainActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Every Android app needs an `manifests/AndroidManifest.xml`. It contains general information about the app, like the app's name, icon and (what's causing the error) a list of all activities used in the app. In this files "application" tag you need to insert this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

This declares the activity "MainActivity" as the activity to start, when launching the app.

> 2- Error:(553, 69) String types not allowed (at 'activity_horizontal_margin' with value '').

As Ben P. mentioned the `Main.xml` from the guide refers to a `dimen` resource named `activity_horizontal_margin`. To adress this error you either have to declare it in the `res/values/dimens.xml` file, or replace that code by some explicit values.

> 3- Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

This error could occur, just because it couldn't find the requiered resources (like in error 2). The same error occured [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884214/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources-com-android-ide-co)  already, because of another missing resource. So fixing the other 2 issues should adress this error too.